# Combobox with javascript on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, combobox

I'm using Ruby on rails.
Does somebody know how can I insert a javascript function on a combobox?
My combobox takes info from my database (only three rows), I have this:

```
<%=select("post", "user_id", @usertype.collect {|p| [p.type_user]},{:include_blank => 'None'}) %>
```

I want the equivalent to:

```
select id="post_user_id" name="post[user_id]" onChange="showUsersFromThatType()">
option value="">None</option>
option value="boss">boss</option>
option value="student">student</option>
option value="technicial">technicial</option></select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of js do you want to add? onclick?  And what is "None boss student technicial"

Comment: Sorry I mean: 
select id="post_user_id" name="post[user_id]" onClick="showUsersFromThatType()">
    option value="">None</option>
    option value="boss">boss</option>
    option value="student">student</option>
    option value="technicial">technicial</option></select>
in place "None Boss student technicial". 
And yes onClick

Comment: I've solved with:
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Usuario" %><br />
    <%= f.select :user_id, @user.collect { |record| [record.firstname, record.id] } %>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag("post", @usertype.collect {|p| [ p.type_user, p.type_user ] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})  %>
```

`@usertype` is a collection and has variable\method `type_user`